# Intercomparison of SciPy minimisation algorithms

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, minimization, scipy-optimize-minimize

I've recently begun to use the `scipy.optimize` minimisation library, and am experimenting with different algorithms.

I see there's good documentation for each algo individually on the [docs page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), but does anybody know of any intercomparison work that's been done (particularly with reference to those available to scipy)?

For instance, I'm finding that SLSQP is much faster than L-BFGS-B but often doesn't do quite as well..

Comment: Depends heavily on use-cases. I could have sworn, that L-BFGS-B is dominating SLSQP completely in most cases in regards to speed (only), which would also be expected theory-wise (for starters: it's less general; unconstrained). I would be careful with ` SLSQP is much faster` without saying what that means (e.g. *local-optimum* with `1e-8 objective tolerance`) and `often doesn't do quite as well..` does not make much sense as both are local-optimizers and should convergence to the same optimum. If that's not the case, there is probably a problem in the model (e.g. not twice diff; not scaled).

Comment: Hi Sascha, yeah it's possible that there is a problem in the model then!

Could you drop a link or briefly explain what you mean by 'twice diff' and 'scaled'?

Comment: Most optimizers (within scipy.optimize) assume that the objective (and constraints if part) are twice [differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function), a common thing in general nonlinear-optimization. This renders lots of stuff wrong as used by people (`if` in functions; `abs` and so on). *Scaling* is somewhat the process of *balancing* model and data such it's *nice* in regards to numerics. Sometimes you calculate with seconds and the algebra needs to compare values like `1e8, 1e1` (bad due to fp-calc)  in gradient-calc which would be different if *days* would be used.